# How can I create an HTML table from a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an html table. It should have two columns and x amount of rows.

```js
var row = 1;

var test = [{
  device: "deviceA",
  tasks: ["task1", "task2", "task3", "task5"]
}]

var display = document.getElementById("device=table-body");

var newRow = display.insertRow(row);

var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML = test[0]["device"]
cell2.innerHTML = test[0]["device"]
```

```html
<table id="device=table-body"></table>
```

I tried the code above, but it's not displaying anything. Not sure where I'm going wrong. End goal is below:

```
device. || Task
----------------
deviceA || Task1
           task2
----------------
deviceB || task1
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there's a console error:

> The index provided (1) is greater than the number of rows in the table (0). Set your variable to 0.

```js
var row = 0;

var test = [{
  device: "deviceA",
  tasks: ["task1", "task2", "task3", "task5"]
}]

var display = document.getElementById("device=table-body");

var newRow = display.insertRow(row);

var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML = test[0]["device"]
cell2.innerHTML = test[0]["device"]
```

```html
<table id="device=table-body"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have a row inside your table ? if no, replace your variable row value to 0 or -1.

```js
const addRow = id => {

  var test = [{
    device: "deviceA",
    tasks: ["task1", "task2", "task3", "task5"]
  }]

  // Get Table by name
  var display = document.getElementById(id);

  // Insert a row at the end of the table
  var newRow = display.insertRow(-1); 

  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = test[0]["device"];
  cell2.innerHTML = test[0]["device"];
};

addRow("myTable");
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```